# getting access denied while using ml.projects.jobs.list api of Google Cloud Machine Learning Engine

Tags: google-cloud-ml

I am having free tier account for Google cloud platform.

But while executing the request for ml.projects.jobs.list with keeping Authorize requests using OAuth 2.0 "ON"(Cloud Machine Learning Engine v1) I am getting following error:-

```
403

- Show headers -

{
 "error": {
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Access to project denied.",
  "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
 }
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Have you enabled the API? (go to console.cloud.google.com click on the "hamburger" menu in the top left, click on "ML Engine")

Comment: @rhaertel80 shouldn't it throw in this case though a longer message such as "Cloud Machine Learning Engine API has not been used in project ... before or it is disabled...". Are there exceptions to this? Unless the poster has not included the message in its entirety.

Comment: Yes, I have enabled  Google Cloud Machine Learning Engine API

Comment: Again, it's weird to me that you get just an "Access to project denied" message with no further details. The next step would be to check that the account you use to authenticate has the [correct permissions](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/access-control) to list ml jobs.